# Creating a csv file from json with different header values per record

Tags: c#, json, export-to-csv

I have a massive json file that is very nested. I need to write the multiple csv files depending on the name of a certain field, if it exists then add the values to the headers I've created if it does not then create a new one. This is working just fine. However I have ran into a problem where the headers do not match because this particular header doesn't exist for that record.  Example:

```
Header:  Dog   Cat  Mouse  Horse
Record1:  yes   yes  yes   yes
```

// above is an example of a file with all values 
Adding record Two where a header value is not listed at all

```
Header:  Dog   Cat  Mouse  Horse
Record1:  yes   yes  yes   yes
Record2:  yes   yes  yes   ***
```

Record2 above does not have a mouse on the record but because it doesn't line up the yes shifted left.  I need to write a Null under than header before spitting out the values to the file.  Below is my code if you could help that would be great as I'm lost at this point:

```
        static List<string> headList = new List<string>();
        static List<string> newHeaderList = new List<string>();
        static List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
        static List<string> oldHeadList = new List<string>();
        static void Main()
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(File.ReadAllText(
                          @"C:\Users\nphillips\workspace\2016R23\UITestAutomation\SeedDataGenerator\src\staticresources\seeddata.resource"));
            string fileName = "";
            var bundles = data.RecordSetBundles;

            foreach (var bundle in bundles)
            {
                var records = bundle.Records;
                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    var test = record.attributes;
                    foreach (var testagain in test)
                    {
                        // Getting the object Name Ex. Location, Item, etc.
                        var jprop = testagain as JProperty;
                        if (jprop != null)
                        {
                            fileName = jprop.First.ToString().Split('_')[2] + ".csv";
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    string header = "";
                    string value = "";
                    foreach (var child in record)
                    {
                        var theChild = child as JProperty;
                        if (theChild != null && !theChild.Name.Equals("attributes"))
                        {
                            // adding the name and values to list
                            headList.Add(child.Name);
                            valueList.Add(child.Value.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    // calling method to write columns and values
                    writeCSV(headList, valueList, fileName);
                    valueList.Clear();
                    headList.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void writeCSV(List<string> headList, List<string> valList, string fileName)
        {
            string headerString = "";
            string value = "";

            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                foreach (var header in headList)
                {
                    foreach (var val in valList)
                    {
                        value += val + ",";
                    }
                    oldHeadList.Add(header);
                    headerString += header + ',';
                }

                headerString += "+" + Environment.NewLine;
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, headerString);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var header in headList)
                {
                    foreach (var oldHeader in oldHeadList)
                    {
                        foreach (var val in valList)
                        {
                            if (header != oldHeader)
                            {
                                value += "null,";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                value += val + ",";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            File.AppendAllText(fileName, value);
            value += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

My horrific json file that I cannot change as its used by my company: https://codeshare.io/rGL6K5

Answer (score 0):

Is there some kind of pattern? 
Reason I am asking is, maybe you could create a service that serialize the JSON to a complex object(s). Once that is done have a service that serializes that object to csv. The service would know to write multiple csv files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stay away from using {dynamic}, if there is a reliable pattern to the JSON.  I'd get a sample JSON file, copy it into the clipboard and using the Paste JSON to Classes feature in Visual Studio.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/

After that, deserialize it with Newtonsoft.JSON into a nice reliable object from which to build your CSV.